# Is American Express accepted in Bangkok?

Tags: money, thailand, payment-cards, bangkok

I'll be traveling to Bangkok soon and I was wondering if restaurants and vendors accept AmericanExpress?

Answer (score 9):

You'll find that the major restaurant chains (the ones found in Central Malls) accept Amex, as do many of the department stores and major brands. High end restaurants, bars and clubs, as well as 4*+ hotels are also no problem.

Outside of the above then many restaurants accept only visa or master, and even then, they may badger you for cash or a surcharge.

For car rental, Avis and Hertz willingly accept Amex but Sixt will grumble and often refuse. Thai RentACar accept only visa/master.  Most PTT, Shell and Caltex gas stations accept Amex.

In general, establishments in keeping with Amex's lifestyle brand will normally accept the card - but then you can enjoy such places anywhere in the world.  Bangkok is best enjoyed 'raw'.  So to get the most out of your trip, I'd recommend a pocket full of cash and a visa/master as backup.

Comment: A small correction. "Pockets full of cash" may introduce risk of pickpockets. The rule of thumb for myself is: your cash money depend on the distance to the nearest major shopping mall, hotel, or banking branch where you can use an ATM. And avoid lonely standing ATM's, too. I don't recall myself carrying more than 3-4 thousand THB (~$100) unless I'm deliberately going to buy something big.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I was speaking more metaphorically than literally. 2,000-3,000 Baht is more than an adequate amount to carry.  As for pickpockets, Bangkok is considerably safer than many U.S. and European cities and in over 150 trips to the city I have never encountered any problem.